# App in background sound disappears WebRTC with Reactnative

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webrtc

After a while the connection is disconnecting while the application is in the background. I’m testing on Android how can i prevent disconnect problem.

I ask this question here [react-native-webrtc](https://react-native-webrtc.discourse.group/t/app-in-background-sound-disappears/43/2) but i couldn't implement any solution.

Can anyone please provide a example with https://github.com/oney/RCTWebRTCDemo because i can’t understand exactly how to use react-native-callkeep or an Android ongoing notification.

I tried to use backgroundjob for keep app alive but it's work only short time period like 5-10 minute.

Comment: did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When your app go to background you should always close the webrtc connection due to safety, you can't leave the camera or sound open.

Why you want your app to be alive in background when webrtc is enabled?

Try this repo https://github.com/DimitrisTzimikas/RCTWebRTCDemo2

Comment: Same reason why it does whatsapp or phone call (etc).

Comment: Don't have whatsapp sorry. So you want phone call like app rather skype.